# How to use 'Group By' when joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables StudentMaster and StudentQualificationDetalis and have some data like below.
[image]

The MarksPercentage Column is varchar

```
I need result like-
details of students who have AdmissionBase = 10+2 and
Get the number of students in AdmissionBase having percentage 50% - 60% and
61% - 70% and
71% - 80% and
81% - 90% and
91% - 100%
```

An example of result that I want is-

```
**AdmissionBase          Percentage          NumberOfStudents**
10+2                     50% - 60%           3
10+2                     61% - 70%           2
```

Above is just an example. Records in the table may vary.

Here is what I have tried

```
SELECT          sm.AdmissionBase,
                (
                CASE
                WHEN sq.MarksPerecent IS NULL OR sq.MarksPerecent = '' THEN 'Not Known'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) >= 50 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) <= 60 THEN '50% - 60%'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) >= 61 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) <= 70 THEN '61% - 70%'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) >= 71 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) <= 80 THEN '71% - 80%'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) >= 81 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) <= 90 THEN '81% - 90%'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) >= 91 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL, sq.MarksPerecent) <= 100 THEN '91% - 100%'
                ELSE 'Below 50%'
                END
                )Percentage,
                COUNT(*)
FROM            StudentMaster sm, StudentQualificationDetails sq
where           sm.registerationnumber = sq.registerationnumber
and             sm.AdmissionBase = sq.ExamDescription
and             sm.admissionbase = '10+2'
group by percentage
```

But it gives me error- Invalid column name 'percentage'.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: You should attempt to solve it before you ask and post your attempt along with the question

Comment: Okay, I wasted my whole day achieving this but nothing worked. I'll post my try within few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more simplified version of what Zoff offered.  it uses a self-created group by table to work with for the join..  I have the last entry to 101 percent since the join is based on a >= and < context.

```
SELECT
      sm.AdmissionBase,
      PctRanks.Grp,
      COUNT(*) as TotalPerGroup
   from 
       StudentMaster sm
          JOIN StudentQualificationDetails sqd
             ON sm.RegistrationNumber = sqd.RegistrationNumber
             JOIN ( select 'Less than 50%' as Grp, 0 as AtLeast, 50 as LessThan
                    UNION select '50% - 60%   ', 50, 61
                    UNION select '61% - 70%   ', 61, 70
                    UNION select '71% - 80%   ', 71, 80
                    UNION select '81% - 90%   ', 81, 90
                    UNION select '91% - 100%   ', 91, 101 ) PctRanks
                ON sqd.MarksPercent >= PctRanks.AtLeast
                AND sqd.MarksPercent < PctRanks.LessThan
   where 
      sm.AdmissionBase = '10+2'
   group by
      sm.AdmissionBase,
      PctRanks.Grp
```

Explained per request.
First, you COULD create a table as Zoff offered, but I prefer to do smaller purpose tables in-line.  So, the query wrapped as ( query ) PctRanks does this inline.  By doing a simple select of values with "AS" column names will imply 1 row.  By doing a union of each other creates additional rows to the same result set.  This results in the PctRanks result set of the columns "Grp", AtLeast, and LessThan columns and 6 rows.

Next, start with your master students list.  You only cared about those with the specific admission base and the WHERE clause should be simple on its own.

Now is the mix... The Student Master aliased "sm" (only those of AdmissionBase = '10+2') and join to the StudentQualificationDetails table aliased "sqd" to simplify readability.  The join is based on the student's Registration Number.  Finally, from the sqd entry, join that to the temp result set "PctRanks" where the MarksPercent is within the range of the two number ranges you were concerned on collecting.

The final columns were to get the admission base, the literal description for the % ranges, and the generic COUNT(*).  Since doing an aggregate function (such as count(), min(), max(), avg(), sum()), the engine needs to know how to apply the common elements (hence your % group labels).

Comment: Well. This really worked! Thanks so much. But I actually didn't understood what you are trying to do here. Can you please explain it?

Comment: @kamalpreet, revised answer... does that help you more.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table to hold your bands. Something like this

```
DECLARE @PercentageBand TABLE
(
    MinPercent    float,
    MaxPercent    float,
    BandName      varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @PercentageBand
    VALUES  (0, 10,'0 - 9.9%'),
            (10, 20, '10% - 19.9%')
            (etc.)
```

And then join against this table with the other two:

```
SELECT      M.AdmissionBase,
            B.BandName,
            COUNT(m.RegistrationNumber) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM        StudentMaster               M
INNER JOIN  StudentQualificationDetails D ON M.RegistrationNumber = D.RegistrationNumber
INNER JOIN  @PercentageBand             B ON D.MarksPercent >= B.MinPercent
                                         AND D.MarksPercent <  B.MaxPercent
GROUP BY    M.AdmissionBase,
            B.BandName
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to calculate the Range on the fly (by dividing by 10 and cutting the fraction)?
You can also use it in your GROUP-BY-Statement:

```
SELECT 
  sm.AdmissionBase,
  Floor(sqd.MarksPercent/10) AS Percentage,
  COUNT(sm.RegistrationNumber) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM StudentMaster sm
INNER JOIN StudentQualificationDetails sqm ON (sm.RegistrationNumber = sqm.RegistrationNumber)
WHERE
  sm.AdmissionBase = "10+2"
GROUP BY sm.AdmissionBase, FLOOR(sqd.MarksPercent/10)
```

Comment: MarksPercent column is varchar

Comment: Are you kidding? Why?

If it is so, you can add a conversion from Varchar to Float - it is pretty simple, but mostly specific for your DBMS. Google will help.